# Plotting a track from a GPX file without a map using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, polyline, gpx

I'm looking to plot and display a line in a web page showing the outline of a GPX track. I've done this as an overlay on a Google map, but I can't find any libraries or suggestion anywhere for displaying a simple visualisation of the track without also using a map. Ultimately this will be overlaid on an MPEG video, but for now I just need to work out how to display the line and I can take it from there. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Leaflet has a video overlay: https://leafletjs.com/examples/overlays/ maybe that's what you need